# How do you get the store's menu using the Uber Eats API?

Tags: rest, get, uber-api

Can the menu for a store be requested by anyone using the API, or is it only available for the store that uploaded the menu?

https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v2/get-eats-stores-storeid-menus

I tried making the API GET request on Postman but it didn't work for me.

Comment: if you have the scope for `eats.store` you should be able to access the menu with this api.